# Best ImageMagick parameters to upscale image containing text

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-filter

What are the best ImageMagick parameters to upscale an image that contains text in Latin alphabet?

Take this image as example:
[image]

I did some experimenting, for example:
`magick convert in.png -filter lanczos -resize 400% -unsharp 0x1 out.png`

But in the resulting image the text is not of the same color, there are shades of gray:

[image]

My original image is grayscale (not black and white), but that seemed to change the color of the original text and made it blurry.

Comment: You'd do better to OCR it. if you simply look at the original image crudely zoomed, you'll see it did a fair job, considering it has very little to work with - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVChk.png

Answer (score 1):

Resizing a raster image will always produce some kind of blur, large scale factors will show it clearly.

To understand this fact and many others with digital image conversions and related issues; please do read up on the basics, presented freely here:
https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/learn-photography-concepts.htm
*("Understanding Sharpness" the most suiting subject here, but understanding it all will help)*

But then:
https://appimage.github.io/Upscayl/
may give better results, but as it is oriented against photos, I can imagine that TEXT still will be problematic (have not tried that).

OCR is most likely the best option; create "text" of it, then use a larger typeface/font.

Comment: My original image also has images inside it.  And also text in different typefaces with headers etc. With page layouts I have to preserve. So I cannot just OCR it and save it as a txt file.

Comment: Then really, you're going to have to recreate it. You can't enlarge data that just isn't there.

Comment: I'd call the above a "fact of life" that cannot be easliy changed. Now My advice then would be to try out "upscayl", the result on scaling images is quite astonishing.